# how to launch the tor browser from a snap install?

Tags: apt, security, snap, browser, tor

see first:

https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/318/857

---

Trying to launch `tor` I get prompts to install with `apt` whereas I'm using `snap`:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ tor

Command 'tor' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install tor

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ torbrowser-launcher

Command 'torbrowser-launcher' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher

thufir@dur:~$
```

This is after just installing `tor` through `snap`, as below.  How is the browser launched?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo snap install tor 
snap "tor" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ snap info tor
name:      tor
summary:   Anonymising TCP overlay network
publisher: Iain R. Learmonth (irl)
license:   unset
description: |
  Tor is free software and an open network that helps you defend against
  traffic analysis, a form of network surveillance that threatens personal
  freedom and privacy, confidential business activities and relationships,
  and state security.

  Tor will accept connections from other applications on your computer on TCP
  port 9050. If you would just like to browse the web with Tor, see Tor
  Browser instead. This client is configured with defaults that will work for
  most use cases. For advanced use, install tor from your distribution's
  package manager.
services:
  tor: simple, enabled, active
snap-id:      GZm8Xr8BoWoe4y5pN1QJp3OGWyKGbDqc
tracking:     stable
refresh-date: today at 01:10 PDT
channels:
  stable:    0.2.9.17 2018-11-07 (2) 6MB -
  candidate: ↑                           
  beta:      ↑                           
  edge:      ↑                           
installed:   0.2.9.17            (2) 6MB -
thufir@dur:~$
```

I would naively hope that the `snap` install for `tor` would include the browser launcher.  Running Cosmic:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: What do you get if you run only `tor` or `tor-client`?

Comment: Does `exec /snap/tor/2/bin/tor` work?

Comment: I just ran `sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher` which seems to then allow `torbrowser-launcher` -- I think.  It's still downloading and unpacking.  (Was just hoping to use snap.)

Comment: @Rutrus You can busy ports using `netstat -antu`. Also, comments aren't intended for new questions. I'd recommend you to [ask a new one](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your problem:**
`tor` is installed but you can find the browser.

**My answer:**

The name of the browser in repositories used to be `torbrowser-launcher` that's why `tor` package doesn't work for you. Because "tor" is not a browser. It is a protocol. At this moment [I can't find](https://snapcraft.io/search?q=tor%20browser) *torbrowser-launcher* in snap. Maybe it doesn't exist there. But you can install it with *apt*:

```
sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher
```

Comment: preferably all that would be through snap so that it's, presumably, more up to date...

Comment: As far as I know, the launcher downloads the latest browser version. Also, if a snap package is not mantained won't be upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

to be honest i had similar problems last month
installing Tor browser via Either Software,
Synaptic or Snap store. they did not seem to work
loading times of half an hour, not running, not even
installing.

then i went to (last resort)

https://www.torproject.org/download/

i downloaded the linux version (Im running Xubuntu 18)
i unzipped it with xarchiver, in a suitable folder
then runned Tor Browser
(i did not even had to make this file executable)
and it installed immediately, and it ran fine.

Comment: I reluctantly accept your answer.  Not through lack of effort or knowledge on your part!  I was just hoping for an actual solution...preferably simple for fools such as myself...