# How to keep the tor browser updated?

Tags: apt, security, snap, browser, tor

To follow up on a few `tor` questions, how is the `tor` browser kept up-to-date?

Surely, surely, manually downloading it periodically isn't the norm.

see also:

[Tor Browser doesnt launch](https://askubuntu.com/q/1219066/45156)

[how to launch the tor browser from a snap install?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1161618/45156)

Comment: Tor-browser notifies of new updates and an update button appears.

Comment: fair enough @Pilot6 but the question stands:  surely that's not just how people muddle through updating it??

Comment: I update it this way for many years and see no problem at all. Most likely snap will provide updates too.